# JSON schema: how to add properties to an item that references a definition?

Tags: validation, jsonschema

I'm trying to build a JSON schema, but i'm quite confused about referencing, extending, etc.

I have a `selector` definition, that is used as *reference* for two properties : `title` and `image`.

```
const schema = {
  $schema: "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    title:{
      $ref:"#/definitions/selector",
      title:"Item title"
    },
    image:{
      $ref:"#/definitions/selector",
      title:"Item image"
    }
  },
  definitions:{
    selector:{
      type:"object",
      description:"Selectors used to extract datas.",
      properties:{
        path:{
          type:"string",
          title:"Selector path"
        },
        attr:{
          type:"string",
          title:"HTML attribute",
          examples:[
            "src"
          ]
        },
        regex:{
          type:"string",
          title:"Regex pattern",
          format:"regex"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to add some more details to those properties, like having the property `title > path` to be required, while `image > path` would not - something like

```
title:{
  $ref:"#/definitions/selector",
  title:"Item title",
  required:['path']
}
```

But this does not work.

This was a simple example with only two properties, but in my real schema, I do reference `#/definitions/selector` at least 40 times but it needs some variations, among others on the required fields.

So how could I achieve this ?

From what I've seen in the docs it should be possible to add properties to an item that has a $ref, as seen [in the official doc](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#section-7.7.1.1).

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `$defs` instead of `definitions`. It was renamed in 2019-09.

Comment: Can you double check your schema? I copy-pasted your example plus the `required: ["path"]` into https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and it works as intended. If it doesn't work for you, please add a short example on how you validate your schema (e.g., how it is used in code).

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I guess this was it, now it works. Tnx !

Comment: Worth noting that SOME implementations just ignore the value in `$schema`, and may as a result treat it as whatever version they support at the time of building, which may be one which ignores other key/values in an object containing `$ref`.

Answer (score 2):

That should work out-of-the-box with any JSON Schema validator:
[image]

Maybe it does not work because of the syntax error at:

```
properties: {
    title:{
      $ref:"#/definitions/selector",
      title:"Item title"
    },
    image:{
      $ref:"#/definitions/selector",
      title:"Item image"
    },                                   <-- Extra comma?
  },
```